# Open first application from 2nd application which is close

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Below is the code i am using to open other application  from with in my application.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);    
    intent.setComponent(newComponentName("com.demo.iTemp.activity","com.demo.iTemp.activity.SplashActivity"));
```

Now with this I am able to open the application. But I am not able to get back to the main application from 2nd application. For example if I press back button it will exit and will not open Ist applicaton.
    can any body guide me how to open 1st from 2nd again.

Comment: Strictly depends on second Application's behavior .If you navigate to some other Activities within Second Application / override Second Application's Activity you can't go back as you expected .

Comment: Post the manifest for second application

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("br.gov.sinesp.cidadao.android");
startActivity(intent );
```

**OR**

```
startActivityForResult(intent , 1001);
```